# Android SpeechRecognizer how to make continuous?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an Android application that continuously recognizes the user's speech and converts it to text.

I haven't been able to get SpeechRecognizer to work for long periods of time. Is there any way to make it continuously listen? The app does NOT need to run in the background. In fact, it won't run in the background at all.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView resultTextView;
private SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultsText);

    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

    if(SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this)){
        speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {}

            @Override
            public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {}

            @Override
            public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {}

            @Override
            public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {}

            @Override
            public void onEndOfSpeech() {}

            @Override
            public void onError(int error) {}

            @Override
            public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
                List<String> results = bundle.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                resultTextView.setText(results.get(0)); 
            }

            @Override
            public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {}

            @Override
            public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {}
        });
    }

    speechRecognizer.startListening(intent);
}
}
```

Comment: If you are using an `Intent` to use a speech recognizer, you are at the mercy of the app/system service which is actually doing to voice to text behavior. If you want to control the listen period you'll probably have to look at the various cloud vendors.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Any good suggestions? I need accurate results relatively fast. Offline would also be nice, but I'm not sure that's possible with cloud venders.